Cloudwatch Dashboard with Resource Group Based filtering for Lambda
I am trying to create a CloudWatch dashboard for my Lambda functions. In the dashboard, I have a few widgets and need to filter these widgets based on Resource Groups. Essentially, with a single dashboard, I aim to monitor the Lambda functions associated with each application.
For example, I have four Lambda functions, and I’ve tagged two of them with the same tags. When I select the Resource Group, only the Lambda functions associated with the respective tags should be displayed.
The following are the steps I have done so far,

Created tags for the Lambdas
Based on the tags created Resource Groups
The resource groups are populated in a dropdown inside the dashboard

But, when I change the dropdown values, the Lambdas are not changing according to the tags associated with each Resource Group.
I want to replicate the same as what we can see in the automatic dashboards.
Any help appreciated. Thank you
